# nest org-mode tables

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have some data which is most naturally represented like so:

```
| thing 1 | thing 2 | thing 3 |
| TABLE 1 | TABLE 2 | TABLE 3 |
```

where `TABLE i` is an `org` table.  I've been over most of the [documentation on tables](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tables.html#Tables), but I didn't see any syntax related to nesting.  Ideally, the nested tables would also export nicely to HTML.

So, I have two related questions (thanks in advance!):

1. Is it possible to make nested `org` tables?
2. If not, is there a workaround to include tables within other tables for export?

Comment: There is a lot I don't currently understand about working with org as a spreadsheet.  If that's where the answer lives, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: That seems possible, but some elisp code would need to be written. Here's some inspiration for you - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48508/merge-org-tables

Comment: 1. No. 2. Not that I know of. You can refer to tables by giving them a name and putting those names in another table, but that does not help with formatting tables for export. The spreadsheet stuff is also not going to help with export. You'll either need to resort to ugly hacks (table entries that contain bare HTML) or change the representation to something that is more org-amenable or give up on Org mode and use something else.